# What actually mixins return?

Tags: sass

I am wondering that what @mixin of Sass actually returns!

I know that there is @function with Sass, and it has @return.

I am not asking what I can return with mixin, but it is more like

what actually mixins return.

Is it just void? or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange question, they return a block of code.

```
@mixin flex($fxd: column, $jc: center, $ai: center){
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: $fxd;
  justify-content: $jc;
  align-items: $ai;
}
```

When you use mixin

```
@include flex;
```

It returns the code inside with default values.